# Can I add a protocol to a Mogenerator-generated class file

Tags: ios, xcode, protocols, nsmanagedobject, mogenerator

I'm using Mogenerator to generate my class files in my iPhone app.

I have a Staff base model which I want to extend using different protocols eg. protocols like manager, security etc but a staff member may be entitled to both manager and security protocols.

So let's say the Staff concrete model looks like the following:

**Staff**

String firstName, lastName

And then the manager protocol can have say a managerialLevel property and the security protocol can have a passCode property.

Some staff members should have one of the other, some should have none and some should have both.

However, I don't see how I can use protocol with Mogenerator. Up to now I use the xcdatamodelId file to create concrete classes and their properties but I want these protocols to add properties to some staff models.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you explain the problem a bit more, perhaps with a concrete example? - mogenerator creates two class files per entity, and one of them can be customized by you, so you can add the protocol methods to that file.

Comment: Yes but can you add protocol properties? I added an example - sorry for the bad formatting!

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get it. A protocol is a "contract" consisting of a list of methods and properties. A class conforms to a protocol if it implements all the required methods/properties. That "some staff members should have one or the other" does not make sense to me.

Comment: Why don't you add all the properties in the model and also add a `type` property that identifies what should be set? How do you think the protocols will help?

Comment: @Ger: In other words: a *class* conforms to a protocol, not an *instance* of a class. You could make "Manager" and "Security" a subclass/subentity of "Staff", and add properties/methods to the subclasses. The problem would be that one object could not be both "Manager" and "Security". - Alternatively you could use optional properties (or a "type" as Wain suggested).

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, I'm not being clear enough. I understand protocols and that they should be used here but I'm struggling to see how I can use them with Mogenerator...

Comment: @Ger: And I am still struggling to understand the question :-) You can add methods to the Mogenerator created classes (the ones without leading underscore), so where is the problem? - Perhaps you can show a concrete protocol and what the classes should look like.

Comment: @MartinR The problem is with persisting protocol specific attributes on the model. There's no problem adding protocol *methods* to the generated classes but when I add a property then it doesn't get persisted to the DB. Get me? :-)